# How to do this in Django templates

Tags: javascript, django, templates, django-templates, dry

Now this is going to be a little weird use-case. Maybe someone has some ideas.

**Background**

I'm writing a website that is very AJAX intensive. In fact there are hardly any full page reloads. This implies that a lot of template composition is done on the client side. For the moment I use some self written scripts in jQuery. To keep things reasonably simple I only use variable placeholders, like this: `{{ somevar.someattr.someotherattr }}`. I could probably use something like mustache to achieve a similar behaviour.

On the other hand, from time to time I like to be able to do some composition on the server side. I'm looking for a way to avoid pointless code duplication on the client & server side.

**Idea**

I'd like to be able to render Django templates in such a way, that certain gaps in the output would remain untouched. More specifically if a given variable is not supplied in the template rendering context, then the placeholder should still read `{{ contents }}`. I wonder whether this or a similar behaviour is possible to achieve using filters and/or tags.

I could just write `{{ somevar.someattr|default:"{{ somevar.someattr }}" }}`, however this isn't very DRY.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` to `{{%s}}`

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID

Comment: ... however this seems to be just for debugging purposes only and a global setting right?

Comment: That is the recommended thing, especially if you are using other apps like Admin. But I have found it to not break anything. I mentioned it because, well it is there. It is upto you to choose how it affects you.

Comment: I think I'll use some hack around this capability.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Django but something that maybe worth a look at is javaScriptMVC: http://javascriptmvc.com/

Comment: This is very interesting. However an attempt to use this would actually force me to totally rewrite the app. Also from what I understand this forces me to actually architect an app as a strict SOFEA, which I'm not ready to do just yet.

Comment: Ok, I didn't use jmvc in the end, however your little remark inspired me to do some more thorough research on what's available and I found `Backbone.js`, which in a sense has a lot in common. I'm really pleased that I found it. Probably saved myself a lot of time, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I came up with in the end:

**Code:**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='tmpl')
def tmpl_filter(value, arg=None):
    return value or ("{{ %s }}" % arg)

@register.tag(name='tmpl')
def tmpl_tag(parser, token):
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endtmpl',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return UpperNode(nodelist)

class UpperNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, nodelist):
        super(UpperNode, self).__init__()
        self.nodelist = nodelist
        nodes = self.get_nodes_by_type(template.VariableNode)
        for n in nodes:
            v = n.filter_expression.var
            if v.lookups:
                for i, f in enumerate(n.filter_expression.filters):
                    print f
                    if f[0] == tmpl_filter and len(f[1]) == 0:
                        n.filter_expression.filters[i] = \
                            (f[0], [(False, '.'.join(v.lookups))],)

    def render(self, context):
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
```

**Usage:**

```
{% load placeholders %}
{% tmpl %}
    {{ var.for.template|tmpl }}
    {{ regular.var }}
    {% nestedtag %}
        {{ another.var.for.template|tmpl }}
    {% endnestedtag %}
{% endtmpl %}
```

It's a hack, but not such a big one to cause actual trouble. Also I think it's thread-safe, however haven't tested it in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use with Django + ICanHaz.js. With this you can use filter or tags:
http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/4282971041/using-jquery-templating-icanhaz-js-with-django

Comment: Nice, I'll definitely try this out.

Comment: I've a question. Does this handle import tags as well? What about block extension?